# Why did STS-32 require 11 major firings of Columbia's maneuvering engines?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, space-shuttle, orbital-maneuver, engines, rendezvous

I was reading the [Mission Safety Evaluation Report for STS-32](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19920014000.pdf) and I noticed the following passage:

> The STS-32 rendezvous was one of the most complex the Space Shuttle
>   had ever attempted, **requiring 11 major firings** of Columbia's
>   maneuvering engines.

That seems pretty high to me. Now my space flight experience only extends to Kerbal, but through those simulations I found that you can generally get into any rendezvous orbit in just 4-5 burns. Why did it take 11 this time?

Comment: While I don't have an authoritative answer, in this case, the rendezvous target was a payload designed to test exposure to space.  I would imagine the rendezvous profile was especially designed to minimize the risk of contamination from thruster plumes, far more so than other cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, remember that report is really old. A quick review of the wonderfully informative [History of Space Shuttle Rendezvous](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110023479.pdf) shows that 9 or 10 burns* are not unusual for a rendezvous (see, for example, the writeups on STS-49 and STS-130).

* depending on whether you include OMS-2 in the count or not

[image: STS-49 shuttle relative motion profile (May 1992)]

There were some off-nominal events with the STS-32 rendezvous, however. As detailed in [Lessons Learned from 7 Space Shuttle Missions](http://klabs.org/DEI/lessons_learned/shuttle/cr-2007-2136974.pdf), problems with the onboard radar resulted in flying a trajectory different from that planned, and additional braking towards the end. This may account for the additional burn(s).

[image: Relative motion plot illustrating the planned and actual trajectories]

Comment: I haven't tracked down the mission report yet, but as the mission included both a satellite deployment and a rendezvous, it seems likely that there would be a plane change in between, accounting for another burn or two. In addition, the mission continued for a few days after the collection of the LDEF, and they may have wanted to establish a different orbit after the pickup.

Comment: I agree with all you say, however, the context of remark in the Mission Safety Evaluation Report implies that the 11 burns were solely related to the LDEF rendezvous. "STS-32
rendezvous
was one of the most complex
the Space Shuttle
had ever attempted,
requiring
11 major
firings of Columbia's
maneuvering
engines.
All burns were completed,
and LDEF
was
grappled
by the RMS at 10:16 a.m. EST on January
12 at a distance
of approximately
35 feet from Columbia."

Comment: Ah, yeah, my misread again.

Comment: STS-49 was a much hotter mess than was STS-32. Multiple rendezvous failures on flight day 4, followed by multiple failures on flight day 6, and by flight day 7, when STS-49 finally did capture Intelsat VI, the pluming from all those failed attempts had pushed the Intelsat 90 degrees off from expected attitude. I need to incorporate this into my talk on software testing tomorrow.